# An error occurs while trying to run a script on my server

Tags: java, plugins, server, minecraft

I am trying to develop a factions plugin, which runs a script per command that is run. So I have a CommandListner script which gets activated by Main.java in onEnable and the listener uses arguments to determine which command is run and run a script which executes that command.

The API that I used can be found here: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/
(It's the 1.8 version)

I have tried a ton of stuff to fix this, I can remember the error being worse/bigger, but I have resolved a part of that. But I can't seem to be able to find the solution to this.

```
package net.evolvedmc.evolvedfactions.commands;

import java.awt.Color;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import net.evolvedmc.evolvedfactions.Main;

public class CommandListner implements CommandExecutor {
    
    private Main plugin;
    
    public CommandListner(Main plugin) {
        
        //Listens for the /f command
        this.plugin = plugin;
        String STRBaseCMD = "f";
        System.out.println("[EvolvedFactions] Listning for command '" + STRBaseCMD + "' with executor " + this);
        plugin.getCommand(STRBaseCMD).setExecutor(this);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        
        //Defines our player
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        
        //checks if the player has given enough arguments
        if(args.length == 0) {
            player.sendMessage(Color.RED + "Correct usage: /f <arg>");
            return false;
        }
        
        //checks if our argument is help
        if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
            
            //checks if the player has the permission to execute this command
            if(player.hasPermission("evolvedfactions.default.help")) {
                
                //loads the script which executes the command
                player.sendMessage("BomPom");
                new HelpCommand(this, player);
                return true;
                
            } else {
                player.sendMessage("You do not have permission to execute this command.");
            }
            
            
        }
        
        return false;
    }

}
```

```
[23:59:56 INFO]: [EvolvedFactions] Enabling EvolvedFactions v0.1
[23:59:56 INFO]: [EvolvedFactions] Activating CommandListner script
[23:59:56 INFO]: [EvolvedFactions] Listning for command 'f' with executor net.evolvedmc.evolvedfactions.commands.CommandListner@6a47bd0b
[23:59:56 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling EvolvedFactions v0.1 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.evolvedmc.evolvedfactions.commands.CommandListner.<init>(CommandListner.java:22) ~[?:?]
        at net.evolvedmc.evolvedfactions.Main.onEnable(Main.java:14) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:335) [server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:356) [server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:316) [server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.q(MinecraftServer.java:402) [server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:370) [server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:325) [server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:211) [server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:505) [server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_221]
```

Comment: You import these packages/classes/interfaces/enums. `import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import net.evolvedmc.evolvedfactions.Main;` What are these classes/interfaces? Could you include them in the question as well?

Comment: I now included the API that I used in the question. Hope this is what you wanted/needed.

Comment: I'm also 99% sure that this line: `new HelpCommand(this, player);` is completely pointless. "Hey JVM, create this object for me. Great, now throw it in the garbage."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the command to your `plugin.yml` (This causes `getCommand("f")` to return `null`):

```
main: ...
version: ...
name: ...

commands:
  f:
```

Please read [the documentation](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Plugin_YAML).

Comment: Oh, I tought adding '/f help' was going to do it. Ima try it out tnx.